# How to create a mysql table with multiple foreign keys and multiple columns

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

So I've been researching this for hours and been having no luck in finding something suitable for what I'm trying to do.

I'm currently having two issues: Creating a table with multiple foreign keys referencing the same primary key and splitting these attributes into multiple columns.

In the end, I would like my table to look something like this, where my O-Director_ID is the **primary key** in one column that correlates to all the other ID's (in this case FAD_ID, SAD_ID and SUD_ID) in the other column that are all **foreign keys** corresponding to the **primary key from another table** (Member_ID from crew_member, which already exists).

[image: Desired Table]

Here's what I'm currently trying to do, just to create multiple foreign keys (I don't even know how to go about creating that second column yet):

```
mysql> create table Other_Directing (
    -> O_Director_ID int (4) not null auto_increment,
    -> FAD_ID int (5) not null,
    -> SAD_ID int (5) not null,
    -> SUD_ID int <5> not null,
    -> primary key (O_Director_ID),
    -> foreign key (FAD_ID) references crew_member(Member_ID),
    -> foreign key (SAD_ID) references crew_member(Member_ID),
    -> foreign key (SUD_ID) references crew_member(Member_ID)
    -> );
```

However even this doesn't work, I get this error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'<5> not null,
primary key (O_Director_ID),
foreign key (FAD_ID) references crew_' 
at line 5
```

Thank you and I hope this makes sense.

Regards,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `SUD_ID int <5> not null,` 
to this:    `SUD_ID int (5) not null,`

Comment: Ok WOW...that's embarassing -_-, but my question still stands about the multiple columns.

Comment: your query looks good a and you are using foreign key also correctly.whats your question?

Comment: Well you see the picture I posted? I was told that I needed to create a table like that, where there were two columns and each primary key correlated to each foreign key side by side. 

Was he not being literal and that's already being done or is there a way I can create a new column that will hold duplicate primary keys next to the unique foreign keys?

Comment: well a table can only have one primary key.the primary key can be combination of one or more columns but it will have only one primary key.

Comment: what i mean is if you are thinking to do something like this primary key (O_Director_ID),primary key (someotherid)
    than this is wrong but primary key(O_Director_ID,someotherid) is correct

Comment: I understand that, I guess what I mean is that it would be the SAME primary key, just duplicated for every row that there's a foreign key if that makes any sense?

Comment: Not quite, I meant something like: 

Row 1: 
       Column 1: primary key (O_Director_ID)
       Column 2: foreign key (FAD_ID)
Row 2: 
       Column 1: primary key (O_Director_ID)
       Column 2: primary key (SAD_ID)

...etc.

Comment: ya u can do that multiple number of columns can reference a primary key.

Comment: if you want something else other than the query u have posted in your question than please update your code so that i can give u proper suggestion.:)

Comment: That's the thing though, I have no idea how I would do what I'm trying to communicate in a query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40928/discussion-between-michael-anthony-leber-and-rishabh-raj)

Answer (score 0):

Does your project really necessitate non-default sizes on your int columns? If so, you have a typo... one of your sizes is in <>'s instead of ()'s: `-> SUD_ID int <5> not null` should be `-> SUD_ID int (5) not null`

If you're sure you do want the sizes due to memory constraints:

```
create table Other_Directing (
    O_Director_ID int not null auto_increment,
    FAD_ID int not null,
    SAD_ID int not null,
    SUD_ID int not null,
    primary key (O_Director_ID),
    foreign key (FAD_ID) references crew_member(Member_ID),
    foreign key (SAD_ID) references crew_member(Member_ID),
    foreign key (SUD_ID) references crew_member(Member_ID)
);
```

Comment: Well the reason why I decided to go with non-default sizes was that I was just guessing the max number of ID's that could exist for what I'm creating. 

Is that an unnecessary constraint then?

Comment: Default for int is 4 bytes, which covers the range from -2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647... Usually the default is plenty unless you work for Facebook or something ;)